# Why Form Api behaves differently in route and in custom block?

Tags: forms, blocks, routes

I’ve encountered this issue several time and I don’t know why. I know this not so easy to reproduce but maybe someone has an explanation.

I’ve built several custom modules which return datas from Rest APIs (I use controller, not Form). These modules are in custom block (define in `src/Plugin/Block/HelloBlock.php`) They all work well.

When I made a custom module with Form API that allow user to select a range of date and return a pdf file, I had a weird  bug : pdf file is downloaded but it is always empty (0 ko).

If I display  the form with a route (defined in `module.routing.yml`), then it works.

Do you know why Form Api behaves differently in route and in custom block ?

Code for block:

```
class WebservicesTestBlock extends BlockBase {

    public function build() {

        $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\webservices_test\Form\WebservicesTestForm');
        return $form;

    }

}
```

And in form :

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {


        // here is the code that returns pdf datas from rest api
        // I've omitted this part because it is working
        // The PDF datas is in $test->body

        header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.pdf");
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        //header("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        echo ($test->body);
        exit;

    }
```

Comment: The form submit should return a BinaryFileResponse if you want to issue an immediate download. Also hard to tell from this code but it’s possible your file path for the pdf is incorrect?

Comment: @Kevin The file path is ok, in fact, it a rest api call and the response is correct. I don't know if it is related to FormApi with custom Block.

Comment: There is no code in here related to Rest APIs?

Comment: @Kevin Because I think it is not useful : the call to rest API works and I've also experienced the same issue with SOAP API in an other project. The issue is related I think to the FormAPI in custom block. The form is validated but there is no file downloaded and it works if I use the form directly with the route.

Comment: You shouldn't use low level output functions like echo or header in D8. This results in erratic behavior impossible to debug.

Comment: @4k4 It is an interesting track to explore. Do have an example of module that generate a download file I can study ? Because my code from a simple PHP view seems correct (but not for D8). In my code `$test->body`contains all the pdf. Just need to know how to create a download function with D8 / FormAPI.

Comment: As @Kevin pointed out return a response in `$form_state->setResponse($response)`

Comment: see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/263660/47547

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't this functionality in submitForm firing?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263640/why-isnt-this-functionality-in-submitform-firing)

Comment: @4k4 Your link is perfect. It works and I understand why it is much better to use `$form_state->setResponse($response)` Do you want to post an answer or should I delete my question ?

Comment: No, don't delete, this is a well researched question which might be helpful to find the answers in the duplicate.